# Magnitude of $\Gamma(1/2+it)$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I want to prove that $$|\Gamma(1/2+it)|=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t}}}$$ My idea is to use the formula $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi/\sin \pi s$. Plugging in $s=1/2+it$ and taking absolute values, we get $$|\Gamma(1/2+it)\Gamma(1/2-it)|=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+it\pi)}$$ How to continue from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\Gamma(\bar{z})=\overline{\Gamma(z)}$$ as well as $$| \sin z|^2=\cosh^2 y-\cos^2 x. $$

Comment: Why is it that $\Gamma(\bar{z})=\overline{\Gamma(z)}$? I've never seen this property before. Does it hold for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I see. Looks like it follows from the limit definition of $\Gamma$. Nice property.

Comment: @MikaH. it follows from the Weierstrass product representation. It holds for all points, except at the poles of course.

Answer (score 1):

Well, is it true that $|\Gamma(x)|$ is conjugation invariant on the line $\Re x= \frac12?$ If yes, than what is $\sin (\pi/2 + z)?$ When you do that, substitute $z = it \pi,$ and use the exponential expression for $\sin.$